# Flask + MySQL strange behaviour

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am building a simple web-app which uses existing MySQL DB. It is my first time using Flask and I have been struggling to understand what I am doing wrong for the past couple of hours.

My simple project structure:

```
/root
/app
  __init__.py
  db.py
  forms.py
  views.py
  /templates
   base.html
   index.html
   login.html
config.py
run.py
```

I am trying to query my MySQL DB and fill the template with the result from the query.

My db.py:

```
from app import app
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


class DB(object):
    mysql = MySQL()

    def __init__(self):
        app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'loguser'
        app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'asdzxc'
        app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'log'
        app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'
        app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = 33006
        self.mysql.init_app(app)

    def query_db(self):
        cursor = self.mysql.connect().cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT name from users limit 1")
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        if data is None:
            return "No results from query"
        else:
            return data
```

And in my views.py I have the following:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm
from .db import DB

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    db = DB()
    user = db.query_db()
    print(user) (it prints it here so the db connection works)


    posts = [  # fake array of posts
        {
            'author': {'nickname': 'John'},
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'},
            'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
        }
    ]
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Home',
                           user=user,
                           posts=posts)
```

I get "AssertionError" when I try to assign "user" to the user from the template:

> AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late.To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.

I believe I am violating a major principle of the framework. What is the correct way to pass the data to the template?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use Flask-SQLAlchemy and MySQL-python 1.2 , Successful code and documentation is available on the link below.

http://techarena51.com/index.php/flask-sqlalchemy-tutorial/

From my experience I found that MySQl support is not that good for python 3 atleast, it is better to use PostgreSQL, but that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It's very late to give answer, but it may help someone.

You've to connect to `MySQL` before adding any route source to an API.

It should be in the order of

```
# 1. MySQL setup should be done at first
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'DataBase'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()

# 2. Create API resource after that
api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')
```